# How to interact with an element, but not its pseudo-element children?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-transforms, pseudo-element

I am trying to make a hamburger icon with a simple animation. The code is

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.ham-wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.hamburger {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  width: 80px;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.hamburger:after, .hamburger:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: blue;
  width: 80px;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.hamburger:after {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: calc(8px + 16px + 16px + 8px);
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.hamburger:before {
  margin-top: calc(8px + 16px);
  margin-bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.hamburger:hover {
  transition: all 3s ease;
  transform: scale(0.3);
  opacity: 0;
}

.ham-wrapper:hover .hamburger:after{
  transition: all 3s ease;
  margin-top: calc(8px + 16px);
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
}

.ham-wrapper:hover .hamburger:before {
  transition: all 3s ease;
  transform: scale(0.3);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="ham-wrapper">
  <i class="hamburger"></i>
</div>
```

But when I rotate `.hamburger`, the whole icon rotates. I want the transform property defined in `.hamburger:hover` to act only for `.hamburger`, not on `.hamburger:after` and `.hamburger:before`. I tried using `position:absolute`; property but it does not seems to work. I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: u could move only the pseudo elements. But you cant move the .hamburger and not the pseudos. They are sticked together.

Comment: Small nitpick: you should be using `::before` and `::after`; the single colon versions are deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to need a different approach. [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/) has this to say about the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-selectors:

> "Note that the content is still inside the element they are applied to. The naming sort of feels like they might come, ya know, before or after the element, but it’s really before or after the other content inside."